# ValueError. SKlearn pipeline

Tags: scikit-learn, pipeline

The following sklearn pipeline code raise the following error:

```
ValueError: No valid specification of the columns. 
Only a scalar, list or slice of all integers or all strings, or boolean mask is allowed
```

Here is the pipeline code

```py
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.base import TransformerMixin
from sklearn.preprocessing import QuantileTransformer
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder,OneHotEncoder                                
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split                                                         
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipelinenter
    

# from iris.csv    

X=df[['sepal length (cm)', 'sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)']]
y=df['target']
        
numeric_pipeline = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(), StandardScaler(),QuantileTransformer())
categorical_pipeline = make_pipeline(SimpleImputer(strategy="most_frequent"), OrdinalEncoder())
        
transformers = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("numeric", numeric_pipeline, X),
        ("categorical", categorical_pipeline, y),
    ])

full_pipeline_reg = make_pipeline(transformers, LinearRegression())
full_pipeline_clf = Pipeline(
    steps=[
        ("preprocess", transformers),
        ("clf", LogisticRegression()),
    ])
        
X_transformed = transformers.fit_transform(X)
```

*Please advise*

Comment: Using the error stacktrace, you should be able to target the line that raises the error. Can you please refine the question with it?